# NLog Syslog configuration files

Tags: configuration, nlog, syslog

I am trying to setup syslog in an asp.net core 2.2 project, but I can't find anything that explains this. The sample code on NLog.Target.Syslog doesn't explain enough for a newbie. I have setup logging to file using example code.

```xml
<target xsi:type="Syslog" name="cee-udp">
      <sl:layout xsi:type="SimpleLayout" text="@cee: {&quot;message&quot;: &quot;${message}&quot;}" />
      <sl:messageCreation>
        <sl:facility>Local4</sl:facility>
        <sl:rfc>Rfc5424</sl:rfc>
        <sl:rfc5424>
          <sl:hostname xsi:type="SimpleLayout" text="${machinename}" />
          <sl:appName xsi:type="SimpleLayout" text="DAEMON.MyAppName" />
          <sl:procId xsi:type="SimpleLayout" text="${processid}" />
          <sl:msgId xsi:type="SimpleLayout" text="${threadid}" />
          <sl:disableBom>true</sl:disableBom>
        </sl:rfc5424>
      </sl:messageCreation>
    </target>
```

Can you please explain what I should be putting for machinename - is that the target host or the source? How do I specify the IP of the syslog server? What is process and threadID and where is it getting the variables from?

I have Virtual Syslog Server running on another machine to test this.

Comment: The layout renderers in the example are built-in NLog, see https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers

Comment: I think it's wise to ask the question here: https://github.com/luigiberrettini/NLog.Targets.Syslog/issues

Comment: Thanks - I just needed some guidance on where to start :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add this config target to  section in Nlog.config file of your project :

```
<target xsi:type="Syslog" name="syslogTarget">
  <sl:layout xsi:type="SimpleLayout" text="${message}" />
  <sl:messageSend>
    <sl:udp server="127.0.0.1" port="514" connectionCheckTimeout="0" />
  </sl:messageSend>
</target>
```